# Applying sort and filter to an Angular table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I downloaded an Angular demo app to learn and work my way through Angular basics. I am having issue with applying a filter and sort to a data table. I made it by referring some examples and not sure if it is correct.

My table is :

```
<div class="widget-content" ng-controller="getAllBenchersController">

                <table ng-table="talentPoolList" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in data | filter: testFilter">

                        <td data-title="'#'">{{$index + 1}}</td>
                        <td data-title="'Employee ID'" sortable="'empno'" filter="{ 'empno': 'text' }">
{{employee.employee.employeeNo}}
</td>
<td data-title="'First Name'" sortable="'employee.employee.firstName'" filter="{ 'employee.employee.firstName': 'text' }">
                            {{employee.employee.firstName}}
                        </td>
  </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
```

Controller :

```
myApp.controller('getAllBenchersController', ['$scope', 'employeeTalentPoolServices', function ($scope, employeeTalentPoolServices) {
    employeeTalentPoolServices.getAllBenchers().then(function (result) {
        $scope.data = result.data;
$scope.testFilter = function (item) {
            return (item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'available' || item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'blocked');
        }
   });
```

I have no clue how it works. Can anyone explain and provide a solution to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your json data?

Comment: Its not coming from a json. im taking it from backend API

Comment: Can you update your question with the result of `result.data` that you get?

Comment: @Phoenix did you sort it out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to explain your demo example I've created a similar example to make you understand what's happening in your question.

We have a employees data with different statuses so when I want to display the list of employees I just want show 'fair' and 'good' so I've written a filter function passed to `filter` directive to tell what items should be displayed from  the list.

If you observe the function it takes every item from list and checks for status to match the desired statuses for displaying.

Check out the demo for the same, hope this gives you a clear understanding on what's happening in your Demo app.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('getAllBenchersController',function($scope,$filter){
  
  $scope.data = {employee:[
    
    {'no':1,'name':'max','status':'bad'},
    {'no':2,'name':'fox','status':'good'},
    {'no':3,'name':'juno','status':'bad'},
    {'no':4,'name':'pet','status':'fair'},
    {'no':5,'name':'xyz','status':'good'},
    {'no':6,'name':'shit','status':'bad'},
    {'no':7,'name':'doggy','status':'fair'},
    {'no':8,'name':'hmmm','status':'bad'} 
  ]}
  
  //this test filter is a function which allows me to decide which data should be displayed in this case I've used 'fair' & 'good' status employees to be displayed...
  $scope.testFilter = function (item) {
            return (item.status.toLowerCase() === 'good' || item.status.toLowerCase() === 'fair');
        };
   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" class="widget-content" ng-controller="getAllBenchersController">

                <table>
          <tr ng-repeat="emp in data.employee | filter: testFilter">
                      <td>{{$index+1}} </td>
                      <td> {{emp.no}}</td>
                      <td>{{emp.name}} </td>
  </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
```

Comment: Yes I sorted it out earlier. But your example helped to gain knowledge. Tnx :)

Comment: Cheers ! anytime happy coding mate:)

Comment: Hi mate, pls checkout this question if you have the time :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504608/use-search-bar-to-filter-data-in-data-table-based-on-search-string